# Do VPNs reroute/encrypt all traffic or just traffic to hosts on the remote network?

Tags: networking, vpn

I use VPN to connect to my company's wiki/email/etc. when I'm not in the office. Does VPN encrypt all the traffic between my laptop and the Internet (that is, even non-company hosts such as google.com, etc.) or does it only encrypt traffic between my laptop and the company wiki/email/etc. hosts?

If I'm on a cafe's free wifi, will connecting to the corporate VPN encrypt all of my traffic or just my traffic to the corporate hosts?

Comment: It is completely arbitrary.  The VPN can be setup either way.

Comment: This site is professional sysadmins.  If you are not the administrator of a given system (ie the VPN server), then you are probably asking in the wrong place.

Comment: The answer to all of your questions is "maybe".

Answer (score 2):

well this depends. You can have a VPN from your laptop to your company to access the internal network of the company. In this case only the part between your laptop and your company's VPN end-point will be encrypted.

You can also push all traffic trough a VPN. Mostly this is not the case but it is possible. This would re-route all traffic trough your VPN, making all of your traffic encrypted untill it reaches your companies VPN end-point. From there on it will be unencrypted.

But it is most likely that only the traffic between you and your company is encrypted.

Comment: ***Assuming the VPN is set up to encrypt traffic at all*** -- Yeah, most are, but I've seen some that aren't. Those make me cry.

Comment: terrible tought that that exists and even is possible...

Comment: Why?  Not all VPNs cross the public internet.  Sometimes you only want a Virtual network, and don't need the privacy/security.

Comment: mostly if you do not cross the public internet, you are still on a private network...